# Sidebar doesn't move to the left side of "main" and CSS Grid isn't working as expected on "landscape tablet"

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm experiencing a problem that's been driving me crazy for hours. The main page I'm building is using CSS grid layout and everything is normal until "portrait tablet", but now that I want to adjust the sidebar and grid layout in "landscape tablet" everything gets messed up and the sidebar won't show itself. Even the grid is messed up and isn't following the dimensions I give its column.

The whole project (It's just the main page) with it's codes are in my **[GitHub page](https://github.com/n-ii-ma/Goodie-Club)** and the website itself is **[here](https://n-ii-ma.github.io/Goodie-Club/)**.

I would really really really appreciate it if someone helps me solve this issue that's driving me insane.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one moment i will give you answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi**,

You add styles for `768px => portrait` and forget `768px => landscape`

So it take `320px => landscape` styles

Problem specified in body `grid-template-areas`

It takes this style

```
grid-template-areas:
  "header"
  "main";
```

So sidebar doesn't show up

Just Add In the bottom part in main style
for last edit

```
/* Bottom Banner for Tablet Landscape Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header"
      "sidebar main";
  }
}
```

I Send to you the edit in Pull Request on github see it

Comment: You're my hero! I didn't know I had to be consistent with that particular line of code through all the media queries for landscape tablet. Your answer even helped me solve the grid problem which wasn't adjusting accordingly. Thanks a billion times!